# Receive an E-Mail

Tags: c, email

In the last days I made a SMTP client in C language which connects over SSL to the SMTP-relay of my provider.

This works just fine, but now I do not understand how to receive an E-Mail.

I have a running linux-server where I want to store all Mail's which are adressed to my Domain.

Which 'service' is responsible for this?

Answer (score 1):

POP3 services are responsible to recieve mails.

Comment: So do I understand right, that the SMTP-Server of a provider does send the E-Mail to the POP/IMAP Server running on my device?

Comment: No, SMTP servers sends mail to users by sending it to users POP3 server. Then Users mail client (POP3 client) gets the mails from POP3 server.

Comment: both are me :) we are same person.

Comment: But allow me one additinal question: Which protocol is used by a SMTP-Server to send the E-Mail to the POP-Server? And how do they determine the correct port?

Comment: Haha shame on me :D

Comment: Your clients talk with SMTP server with SMTP protocol to send mail. Then SMTP server talks with POP3 server with POP3 protocol to bring mail to the user. Then users client talk with POP3 server with POP3 protocol to receive it.